# custom message in twilio IVR Call

Tags: twilio

I want to use custom message in twilio call,
I am using call resource as follows

```
Twilio.init(accsid, acctoken);
                Call call = Call.creator(
                        new PhoneNumber(TO), //to
                        new PhoneNumber(FROM), //from
                        URI.create(twilioIvrCallUrl))
                        .setStatusCallback(callbackUrl)
                        .setStatusCallbackEvent(IvrStatusEvents)
                        .setStatusCallbackMethod(HttpMethod.POST)
                        .create();
```

I want to play custom message like "Hi username, Hello world" now username here can be custom. I am not expecting any user interaction just play the provided message. I want to pass this message in call. how this can be done using Call resource ?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You have currently set up your application to make a call, then when that call is answered Twilio will make an HTTP request to `twilioIvrCallUrl` to find out what to do next.

That URL will need to respond with TwiML to tell Twilio what to do, in this case [read out your message using `<Say>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/say). The URL can point to a dynamic endpoint that takes parameters and then produces the `<Say>` with the personalisation you require.

So, if you pass the username in the URL as a query parameter, then read it out of parameters when Twilio makes the request, you can construct your dynamic `<Say>` on the other end.